# ExtJs create custon icon for Ext.MessageBox

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have an ExtJs form which upon receiving a response from server shows a pop-up based on whether the submit was successful or not. The code looks like this:

```
if (form.isValid()) {
    form.submit({
        success: function (form, action) {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Success', action.result.msg);
        },
        failure: function (form, action) {
            Ext.MessageBox.show({
                title:'Failure',
                msg: action.result.msg,
                buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK,
                icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Now, rather than having an alert message for the success, I'd like to also have a Message box with a 'check' icon. It doesn't look like it is available in ExtJS in the same way as Ext.MessageBox.ERROR, so I was wondering how I can create a custom icon to appear there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The icon config option is just a CSS class, define a new one like:

```
.check-icon {
    background-image: url(../img/check.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Then in config:

```
icon: 'check-icon'
```

Should do what you want.

Comment: Hey, so that seems to work, but the image seems to repeat a bunch of times. Visual studio is also saying that 'repeat' is not a known property name. Anyway I can fix that? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, background-repeat, my mistake.

Comment: Thanks!...But, another important thing is that the image must be 32x32 pixels, like I see in this demo: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/message-box/msg-box.html (last example)

Comment: @RiccardoVolpe I don't think it HAS to be, I'm sure I've used smaller 24x24 but I haven't done this in a while so that could have changed now.

Comment: @Lloyd Hello. For images smaller than 32x32, it should not be a problem, but for bigger than 32x32, the image is not displayed well. I refer to a maximum size.